# We are not using ADFS when we log onto AWS servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am going over IAM topic. Understood about Active Directory Federation service (ADFS). We just started on a project. We are going to host a vendor product that we use here on premise onto AWS. I RDP (remote into) into AWS 2012 servers from my office network. When I log onto AWS windows 2012 servers, I see my credentials already on AWS servers. I am pretty sure we are not using ADFS to authenticate users. What else could we be using when we RDP onto AWS servers. I can see my on premise file servers when I log onto AWS servers. Is it possible that when our cloud platform engineers have setup AWS servers, they configured in such a way we can see our on prem servers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you used your domain credentials to RDP to the servers in AWS... The AWS servers would need to be joined to the domain and there would need to be a route from the VPC in AWS back to your on-prem infrastructure in order for either of those things to work, so it sounds like it was configured prior to you logging onto it.